# Get date in center of page

Tags: html, css, rendering

How can I get the dates in the center of the main div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShDNy/2/)

```
<style>
.div_table{
  display:table;         
  width:100%;               
}
.div_table_row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}
.div_table_col{
  display:table-column;
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
}

label
{
width: 10em;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 0.5em;
display: block;
}


input
{
color: #781351;
background: #fee3ad;
border: 1px solid #781351
}

</style>


<div class="div_table">

    <div class="div_table_row">
        <img src="./images/logo_transparent.png" width="192" height="69" alt="Logo" />
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
        <?php include_once("./include/menu.php"); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="div_table_row">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <label>From Date:<br /><input type="text" class="date" /></label>
            <label>To Date:<br /><input type="text" class="date" /></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer div_table_row">All Rights Reserved</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just took a quick look at the JSFiddle (very good that you posted that). But...just a side-comment...there is *a lot* of unnecessary code that could easily be causing various issues. The positioning one, specifically, could be the result of the CSS, as you suspect, or could be a result of some of the JavaScript that you wrote (which there is a ton for a relatively simple form). You may want to consider some refactoring and/or simplifying.

Comment: Also, another note - I see you have a lot of client-side validation. I assume that you are doing server-side validation as well? If not, you should, and then use a JS library to wire the two together. You'll remove (almost) all of your validation code client-side.

Comment: I know its too much of code I have tried reducing as much as possible ses if you can help me with it..

Comment: I am doing the server side validation as well thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whould you like to center the labels or the input textfields?

If labels do this:

```
        <label><span>From Date:</span><br /><input type="text" class="date" /></label>
        <label><span>To Date:</span><br /><input type="text" class="date" /></label>
```

Put the text in the label into a span.

in CSS:

`label span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}`

Add `position: relative;` to `.div_table_row`.